# Using model data annotation in MVC to ensure a string contains just one word?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there some way using data annotations that I can check the value of a property in my model 
is just a single word? I know how to check it's maximum length but I've no idea how to 
do the single word check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.  You can use a regex in your model for the validation.

```
[RegularExpression(@"\b*[a-zA-Z0-9_]\b", ErrorMessage = "Enter A Single Word Please")]
string FirstName {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out. Maybe a small mistake in your answer. I see you set the property as an int :-)

Comment: :) Changed.  I like using regex in the model like that, it works soo nicely.  I do something similiar to make sure that names for folders are only containing letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A single word of only letters and numbers with a minimum length of 4 and maximum length of 50 characters and a message showing the minimum:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z\d]{4,}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid.")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "Must be at least {2} characters long.")]
```

A single word of only letters with a minimum length of 4 and maximum length of 30 characters and a message showing the range:

```
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z]{4,}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid.")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Must be between {2} and {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 4)]
```